# Adding event to public google calender using google api

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am working on a website where he can rent a trailer (http://www.cavalart.be/verhuur_thomas.php).
To make it easy for me to keep an overview of the rentings I connected the page to a google calendar.

It already receives the data from the calendar using the following script:

```
//Controleer data                               
var mykey = 'AIzaSyC_-oIV9yTVPw0Z9sDSM_mLQld_FPmIT4c'; // typically like Gtg-rtZdsreUr_fLfhgPfgff
var calendarid = '7a97f6k4ok8v77jc2po6kkgcuo@group.calendar.google.com'; // will look somewhat like 3ruy234vodf6hf4sdf5sd84f@group.calendar.google.com

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: encodeURI('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid+ '/events?key=' + mykey),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            //do whatever you want with each

    },
    error: function (response) {
        //tell that an error has occurred
    }
});
```

I want to add events based on the user input, using the same kind of programming. Someting like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: encodeURI('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid+ '/events?key=' + mykey),
dataType: 'json',
start: 2016-06-29;
end: 2016-06-29;
description: "rent trailer";
success: function (response) {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        //do whatever you want with each

},
error: function (response) {
    //tell that an error has occurred
}
});
```

How do i solve this issue?

Comment: And what is the *issue* actually?

Comment: It does not work, second part is just dummy code to show what i want to achieve.

Comment: In order to add events to a calendar you will have to authenticate as a user authorized to edit the calendar. You won't want those credentials publicly available on the client so you'll want to have a server side script that adds the actual event.